# Create a function that takes a list of pairs -- learnyouahaskell

Tags: haskell

so I'm trying to understand this function in the tutorial learnyouahaskell and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. As I understand, it should take in a list of pairs and return a list of BMI's from those pairs.

```
calcBmis :: (RealFloat a) => [(a, a)] -> [a]  
calcBmis xs = [bmi w h | (w, h) <- xs]  
    where bmi weight height = weight / height ^ 2
```

Every time I try and run the function with this input, `calcBmis [(1,2),(2.4)]`, I get this error:

```
<interactive>:77:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Fractional (a, a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Fractional (a, a), RealFloat a) => [a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second element is "2.4" instead of "(2,4)". Running "calcBmis [(1,2),(2,4)]" should work.

Comment: Whoops, missed the typo.  Good catch.